# Why is my ArrayList creating two copies of an object?

Tags: java, object, arraylist

Part of my main

```
try{
    Scanner read = new Scanner(file);
    int fix = read.nextInt();
    do{
    for(int x = 0; x < fix; x++){
        String petname = read.next();
        int birthday = read.nextInt();
        String species = read.next();
        double bill = read.nextDouble();
        String owner = read.next();
        Veterinarian work = new Veterinarian(petname, birthday, species, bill, owner);
        Veterinarian.Vet.add(work);
                }
        }
        while(read.hasNextLine() == pick);
        }  
    catch(FileNotFoundException FNF){
        System.err.format("File not found");}
```

this is my class

```
static List<Veterinarian> Vet = new ArrayList<>();

public Veterinarian(){}
public Veterinarian(String petname, int birthday, String species, double bill, String owner){
this.petname = petname;
this.birthday = birthday;
this.species = species;
this.bill = bill;
this.owner = owner;
Vet.add(this);
}
```

I don't know why the add method I'm using is creating two copies of the object into two separate ArrayList's.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you're adding it twice...

```
String owner = read.next();
Veterinarian work = new Veterinarian(petname, birthday, species, bill, owner);
Veterinarian.Vet.add(work); // once

...

public Veterinarian(String petname, int birthday, String species, double bill, String owner){
    this.petname = petname;
    this.birthday = birthday;
    this.species = species;
    this.bill = bill;
    this.owner = owner;
    Vet.add(this); // twice
}
```

Also note, it would [be better practice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705628/758280) to remove the second invocation (in your constructor).

Answer (score 1):

You are adding it in the constructor:

```
Vet.add(this);
```

and you are adding it in the main:

```
Veterinarian.Vet.add(work);
```

Answer (score 0):

the add method is called twice, when you new a instance of Veterinarian using

`Veterinarian work = new Veterinarian(petname, birthday, species, bill, owner)`,

the add method has been called, and you call it again after that

`Veterinarian.Vet.add(work);`