# Is this initialization safe?

Tags: java

I have a class like that:

```
public class WorkHelper {

    private final Worker worker;

    public WorkHelper(Worker worker) {
        this.worker = worker;
    }

    //...

}
```

and everybody knows that the initialization below is wrong:

```
public class Worker {

    private final WorkHelper helper;
    private final SomeClass some;

    public Worker(SomeClass some) {
        helper = new WorkHelper(this);
        this.some = some;
    }

}
```

But how about the one below? Is this correct?

```
public class Worker {

    private final WorkHelper helper = new WorkHelper(this);
    private final SomeClass some;

    public Worker(SomeClass some) {
        this.some = some;
    }

}
```

Comment: Why is the second initialization wrong? You can initialize `final` variables in the constructor...

Comment: @dan1st, there is a cycle initializing there?

Comment: "everybody knows that the initialization below is wrong" Really? I don't see what could be wrong there.

Comment: http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=252

Comment: The problem is passing a partially constructed object to the other class, where some values may not be seen as initialized. There is no difference between 2 and 3 in this respect.

Comment: There is no cyclic initialization.

Comment: Better, if you can, just to use POJOs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All versions are unsafe; they are all cases of “[letting `this` escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705628/256196)”.

Consider creating a factory method that creates the worker helper after construction is complete, for example:

```
public class Worker {

    private WorkHelper helper;
    private SomeClass some;

    // hide the constructor
    private Worker() {}

    public static Worker create(SomeClass some) {
        Worker worker = new Worker();
        worker.some = some;
        worker.helper = new WorkHelper(worker); // pass post construction
        return worker;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, my fault. :)

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow may someone let me know what is OP

Comment: @RealSkeptic perhaps, but OP has probably simplified his/her real life situation to make the question simple and more broadly useful.

Comment: @TheGoldy OP == Original Poster (conveniently gender neutral)

Comment: @Bohemian but why is helper initialized two times?

Comment: @Life44 oops! It got left in from copy-paste. Fixed now.

Comment: @RealSkeptic as I just posted, that was left there in error due to a sloppy copy paste. Have some sympathy - I am thumbing this code in on my phone and only part of my post is visible at any one time due to tiny screen size.