# Don't getters returning objects allow callers direct access to member variables?

Tags: java, oop

Let's say I have a simple class that stores a user's friends in an ArrayList of strings, with a getter to access that ArrayList:

```
public class User
{
  private ArrayList<String> mFriends;
  
  // ...other code like constructors and setters...

  public ArrayList<String> getFriends()
  {
    return mFriends;
  }
}
```

Since Java and many other languages are (equivalently) pass-by-reference, does this not allow the caller of getFriends() **direct access** to my ArrayList of strings i.e. they could modify it without even calling my setter?

I feel this immensely breaks the concept of encapsulation. Is there a normal workaround for this, besides dynamically creating a new ArrayList with the same values and returning that, or am I misunderstanding something?

Edit: I understand that Java is not truly pass-by-reference but rather passes over a copy of the address of the original object, but this has the same effect as pass-by-reference when exposing objects to those outside your class

Comment: What you're protecting against here is outside code modifying which `ArrayList` `mFriends` refers to. But as you've noted, it's still possible for outside code to modify _the contents_ of that list. If you want to protect against that you could perhaps use `Collections.unmodifiableList`, or return a copy.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I mean. How would this work with regards to passing non built-in "standard" Java objects back? Should I just trust the user not to modify its contents without using my setter, for example?

Comment: If it's important that they do not modify the contents, then you should probably make it impossible for them to do so. If you make something available to users, there's quite a high risk that someone will make use of it regardless of what you recommend.

Comment: The short answer is 'yes'. But you have a responsibility as a designer not to expose the internal implementation of your class to the outside world. Making ```mFriends``` private and then providing a getter method for it is no different to making it public. Consider ```return Collections.unmodifiableList(mFriends)``` instead.

Comment: You may be aware that articles like [Why getter and setter methods are evil](https://www.infoworld.com/article/2073723/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html) have been circulating for decades.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Java is **not**, and has never been implementing *Pass by Reference* mechanism, it has always been *Pass by Value*;
2. The problem you are describing is known as [Reference Escape](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3705425/java-reference-escape), and yes, you are right, caller can modify your object, if you expose it via *reference*;
3. In order to avoid the *Reference Escape* problem, you can either:

   1. return a deep copy of the object (with `.clone()`);
   2. create a new object with the existing data (e.g. `new ArrayList<>(yourObjectHere)`);
   3. or come up with some other idea, there are some other ways too do this;
4. This does not really break the Encapsulation, *per se*, it is rather a point of correct design how you implement the encapsulation;
5. Your concern about performance: no, it is not going to break performance, moreover - it has nothing to do with performance; rather it is a matter of *proper design* of the OOP, mandating either *mutability* or *immutability* of the object. If you were to always return a deep copy instead of reference, you would not have a chance to have a good leverage of your object.

   Taking your example: what if you want to change the state of the object without just setting a new object via its setter? what if you want to amend the existing friends (*which is in your example*)? do you think it is rather better to create a new List of friends and set it into the object? no, you are simply losing control over your object in the latter case.

Comment: Thanks, the Reference Escape comment was mostly what I was looking for. This video also is helping me a lot. Appreciate it. (video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nW48K2a6t7k)

Answer (score 1):

If you are worried about encapsulation then you can return a copy of your list e.g.

```
public ArrayList<String> getFriends() {
    return new ArrayList<>(mFriends);
  }
```

By the way, Java is not truly pass-by-reference it's more pass-by-value.

Comment: Yes sorry, I edited my past regarding the pass-by-reference comment. However, I cannot believe that creating a new copy each time would be performant, as I specifically did say in my comments "besides dynamically creating a new ArrayList"

Comment: @GaryAllen That's how it is. And performance should be the least of your worries in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You are right for **mutable** objects. You could wrap the field with [`Collections.unmodifiableList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)) and such. What one also sees, is for (mutable) collections just have no getters, but `addFriend`, `getFriend(index)` and such.

In fact getters (and estpecially setters) are no longer a very esteemed pattern.

The member "m" prefix is imho better suited for other languages.

Comment: Despite the fact, that your answer points to the correct behaviour, I think it's a bit misleading in terms of *Semantics* of what the question asks. It's the problem of Reference Escaping.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri Indeed, I even upvoted your answer. The problem with OOP is that its basic (historical) concept is of internal _state_. Can you reach via access methods some mutable object, then that should be _intended_ behavior.  I primarily answered, because letting getters return a copy did seem a rather weak technique.