# How to properly use a "lock" variable for synchronization in a Serializable class?

Tags: java, deserialization, synchronized

I am trying to figure out how to avoid an NPE in the the code below. I am unable to purposely reproduce the error, but every once in a while I get an NPE at the line 40 `synchronized(lock) {`. My guess is that it's happening after a serialization/deserialization process - but that is just a guess.

My IDE gives me a compile "tip" that says `synchronization on a non-final variable (lock)`, but to be quite honest, I'm not as familiar with `synchronized` code blocks and how a serializable class affects `final` variables.

As an FYI, the code below was copied/modified from a Struts Wiki: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WW/HibernateAndSpringEnabledExecuteAndWaitInterceptor (towards the bottom of the page in the comments).

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionInvocation;
import org.apache.struts2.interceptor.BackgroundProcess;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.EntityManagerHolder;
import org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionSynchronizationManager;

import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.Serializable;

public class OpenSessionBackgroundProcess extends BackgroundProcess implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3884464561311686443L;

    private final transient EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    // used for synchronization
    protected boolean initializationComplete;
    private transient Object lock = new Object();

    public OpenSessionBackgroundProcess(String name, ActionInvocation invocation, int threadPriority, EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        super(name, invocation, threadPriority);
        this.entityManagerFactory = entityManagerFactory;
        initializationComplete = true;
        synchronized (lock) {
            lock.notify();
        }
    }

    protected void beforeInvocation() throws Exception {
        while (!initializationComplete) {
            try {
                synchronized (lock) {  // <----- NPE HERE
                    lock.wait(100);
                }
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // behavior ignores cause of re-awakening.
            }
        }
        EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.bindResource(entityManagerFactory, new EntityManagerHolder(em));
        super.beforeInvocation();
    }

    protected void afterInvocation() throws Exception {
        super.afterInvocation();
        EntityManagerHolder emHolder = (EntityManagerHolder)
        TransactionSynchronizationManager.unbindResource(entityManagerFactory);
        EntityManagerFactoryUtils.closeEntityManager(emHolder.getEntityManager());
    }

    /**
     * Override default readObject() method when deserializing
     *
     * @param serialized the serialized object
     */
    private void readObject(ObjectInputStream serialized) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
        serialized.defaultReadObject();
        lock = new Object();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why does it need to be serializable?

Comment: I only made it serializable since the parent class was.

Comment: OK, but is it actually serialized, and if so, why? This class has no state that seems useful to serialize, so if you do need to serialize a class that references this one, I would make _that_ reference `transient`.

Comment: @TimMoore even worse, the whole race condition of the constructor likely repeats at the deserialization. Unless the base class doesn’t start a background thread of course, in which case the object would be even more broken, not fulfilling its purpose. On the other hand, this would harmonize with the fact that `entityManagerFactory` is not restored upon deserialization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in the question and the linked wiki page has an unresolvable data race condition. Unfortunately, the constructor of [`BackgroundProcess`](https://github.com/apache/struts/blob/master/core/src/main/java/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/BackgroundProcess.java) allows a reference to `this` to [escape the constructor](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/TSM01-J.+Do+not+let+the+this+reference+escape+during+object+construction) by starting a new thread that calls `beforeInvocation`. Because this call can occur before the constructor of the child class completes, it is not safe to extend `BackgroundProcess`.

This code attempts to handle the race condition on `entityManagerFactory` through use of the `lock` object, `initializationComplete` flag, and `wait`/`notify` usage. However, this only moves the race condition from `entityManagerFactory` to `lock`, as Java only [initialises the fields of subclasses *after* the parent class constructor completes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.5). This is true regardless of whether the field is initialised inline or in the constructor.

You can find more details about this problem in the excellent accepted answer to the question [Java: reference escape](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3705628/29470).

My best advice is to avoid the use of `BackgroundProcess` and find another way to solve the original problem.

Comment: Tim - thank you.  Very impressive. If I were to "replace" the `BackgroundProcess` class with the logic in my `OpenSessionBackgroundProcess` class (in other words: do not extend), could I remove the race condition?

Comment: @Burton I'm not too familiar with Struts2, so I'm probably missing enough context to give a qualified answer. It certainly would be possible to implement something like `BackgroundProcess` that doesn't have this race condition. The key change would be to start the thread with a separate method call, after construction completes. I think you would need to reimplement `ExecuteAndWaitInterceptor` entirely to make use of the fixed class. It might be better to fix it upstream in the Struts project if the commiters are willing to work on this.

Comment: Tim - Agreed - and as you suggested the maintenance Struts team ended up refactoring the Background process upstream to use an Executor approach resolving the issue: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WW-3691